# How to automatically inject implementation based on Generics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a Service class defined like this,

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class SomeService<T extends AbstractResponse> {
    private final ValidationService<T> validationService;
    ....
}
```

And I have two kinds of `AbstractResponse`, `ResponseA` and `ResponseB` and have a validation service defined for both of them.

```
@Service("aValidationService");
class AValidationService<ResponseA> implements ValidationService<ResponseA> {
    ....
}
```

and

```
@Service("ValidationService");
class BValidationService<ResponseB> implements ValidationService<ResponseB> {
    ....
}
```

Right now spring is throwing an error because it's not able to deduce the implementation of `ValidationService` to use in `SomeService` as there are two implementations of it. How do I make spring deduce the correct implementation based on the type of AbstractResponse?

Comment: Your concrete classes should have generic parameters on them; just `class BService implements Service<B>`.

Comment: How would spring know the type of response in `SomeService`? Just by looking at the code I as a human wouldn't be able to tell so how should a machine be able to? Also note that due to type erasure the type of `T` in `SomeService` would very likely not be known at runtime.

Comment: Is there any way I can dynamically invoke the corresponding validator class inside `SomeService`?

Comment: Why are you defining `AValidationService` and `BValidationService` with a generic parameter? why not `class AValidationService implements ValidationService<ResponseA>`?

Comment: Thank you @MauricePerry for pointing it out. It was a typo from my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that I understood your requirements.

You can not automatically inject, when you have (2) of the same kind.  In this case ValidationService.

You could inject `@ValidationServiceA`, or `@ValidationServiceB`, or a `List<ValidationServiceI>` and then return the one you want based on a `<T> type` you care about:

The solution below highlights that.

The method `getGenericParameter()` is used to return the `<T>` parameter.  This is to avoid the use of Reflection.

The method `methodWhichDeterminesWhichServiceToUseBasedOnResponseType` to used to determine which ValidationService to use based on the input  that you require.

You can find the complete solution below, including a verification Test.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ValidationServiceA implements ValidationServiceI<ResponseA>{

    @Override public Class<ResponseA> getGenericParameter() {
        return ResponseA.class;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Service A");
    }
}
```

---

```
   @Service
public class ValidationServiceB implements ValidationServiceI<ResponseB>{

    @Override public Class<ResponseB> getGenericParameter() {
        return ResponseB.class;
    }


    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Service B");
    }

}
```

---

```
    public interface ValidationServiceI<T>{
    
        Class<T> getGenericParameter();
    
        void print();
    
    }
```

---

```
@Service
public class ServiceWhichCallsOthers {

    @Autowired
    private List<ValidationServiceI> validationServices;

    public <T> ValidationServiceI<T> methodWhichDeterminesWhichServiceToUseBasedOnResponseType(T responseType){

        Optional<ValidationServiceI> validationServiceSupportingResponse = validationServices.stream().filter(validationServiceI -> validationServiceI.getGenericParameter().equals(responseType)).findFirst();

        return validationServiceSupportingResponse.get();
    }

    public void callValidationServiceA(){
        methodWhichDeterminesWhichServiceToUseBasedOnResponseType(ResponseA.class).print();
    }

    public void callValidationServiceB(){
        methodWhichDeterminesWhichServiceToUseBasedOnResponseType(ResponseB.class).print();
    }

}
```

---

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ServiceWhichCallsOthersIT {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceWhichCallsOthers serviceWhichCallsOthers;

    @Test
    public void validateBasedOnResponseType(){

        Assertions.assertEquals(ValidationServiceA.class, serviceWhichCallsOthers.methodWhichDeterminesWhichServiceToUseBasedOnResponseType(ResponseA.class).getClass());
        Assertions.assertEquals(ValidationServiceB.class, serviceWhichCallsOthers.methodWhichDeterminesWhichServiceToUseBasedOnResponseType(ResponseB.class).getClass());


        serviceWhichCallsOthers.callValidationServiceA();
        serviceWhichCallsOthers.callValidationServiceB();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @JCompetence for the potential solution. What I did was bind different use-cases (A & B) to a enum and did something like this,

`class ValidationServiceProvider<T extends EnumType>
   private final Map<EnumType, ValidationServiceI> validators = new EnumMap<>(EnumType.class);

public ValidationServiceProvider(Set<ValidationServiceI> validators) {
  this.validators = validators.stream.collect(Collectors.toMap(ValidationServiceI::getEnumType, Function.identity())));
}

void validate(T resp){
 validators.get(resp.getType()).validate(resp);
        }
}`